# Issue with giving roles with a command Discord Py

Tags: python, discord.py

I have made a command to set someone ROLE, However, it's throwing errors.

```
Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'add_roles'
```

Is there anything wrong I have did? I am using the latest discord py version.

```
@bot.command()
async def set_role(ctx,member = None,val: int = None):
    ab = member
    ab = ab.replace("<","")
    ab = ab.replace(">","")
    ab = ab.replace("@","")
    ab = ab.replace("!","")
    user = bot.get_user(int(ab))
    if val == 1:
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="Test")
        await user.add_roles(role)
        await ctx.send('Updated')
```

Comment: Hey, member is mention? If it is mention, you can get ID from [`member.id`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.id), and if you have a member object - you can use [`member.add_roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.add_roles).

And User is Discord common user, not member of guild / server. User cant get roles bc  you dont have context of guild / server. I think.

Comment: Yes, the member is mentioned, Well your thing is not working. It's throwing errors, the str object has no ID.

Comment: Try use typehint for convert: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#discord-converters, I cant try it right now, but later if I will have time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
user = bot.get_user(int(ab))
```

This creates a user object. It is not affiliated to a guild / discord server. By design you cannot do `add_roles`.
Reason being your bot might not share a guild with this user. Or your bot might share multiple guilds with this user. But how does it know which guild you are actually adressing?

You need to create a member object. This could be done with:

```
member = ctx.guild.get_member(int(ab))
```

Now you have a member object and you can await add_roles.

```
await member.add_roles(role)
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.add_roles

Answer (score 0):

to give a role to a member u need to give the member and the name of the role as inputs.
for example:

" ?set_role @clay#9871 example "

the bot gonna search for a role name 'example' from the guild roles
if the bot didn't find the role it will send "role not found" that's what the "try" and "except" for

```
@bot.command()
async def set_role(ctx,member :discord.Member,role):
    try:
      add_role= discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=role)
      await member.add_roles(add_role)      
      await ctx.send('Updated')
    except:
      await ctx.send("role not found!")
```

Comment: Hi @hachem, please add some details to explain the code of your answer. Thanks!

Comment: hello @baikho thanks for informing me i edited my answer check it out